# Accessing values of cells from selected Rows in EXCEL using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I have excel sheet from which I want to update few cell values from Selected rows. How can I do this in VBA? I have not used VBA extensively.

Comment: You need to provide more detail as to what you are doing. Either an example, or a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below link.  This should be what you are after.

http://www.excel-vba-easy.com/vba-programming-range-excel-vba.html

Answer (score 0):

Omky,

Uyou will need some knowledge of VBA anyway. The Application.Selection variable returns to you the Range currently selected. Try to select an area on your Workbook and execute the macro below:

```
Sub AreaSelected()
    MsgBox Application.Selection.Address
End Sub
```

And here you have a full example:

http://www.lazerwire.com/2011/10/excel-vba-get-all-selected-rows.html

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
'put something in column 3 of all selected rows
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection.Rows
        Cells(r.Row, 3) = "test"
    Next r
End Sub
```